# `Access is denied` when I try to create a directory in Windows Vista . . 

Tags: windows-vista, command-line

I'm getting an `access denied` message when I try to create sub-directories of certain directories from the command line in Vista.  I can create folders from the GUI, but I want to be able to avoid the pointing and clicking.

Is there a `sudo` for windows that will let me past this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

Tap your Windows key to bring up your start menu, and type cmd to bring up the prompt program, you should now be able to right click on the icon and select Run as Administrator.

After some UAC clicking you should now have a prompt with escalated privileges.

Comment: Simple, yet nice.  Very good alternative to the other answer :P

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative would be to use the [runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)  command from the command prompt (you could also put it in a batchfile).

```
runas /user:computername\useraccount mkdir thedirtomake\somesubdir\
```

All you need to do is fill in the computer and account names.

Comment: +1 OP was after command line solution. He also asked about `sudo` in Windows and that's what `runas` is.